# kali linux and its feature of wifi hot-spot

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I cant see any option of changing the password of my hot-spot created in Kali.
How can i change the password?
It is always the same password whenever I start hot-spot service.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable your hotspot, click options. In the options menu, select "wireless security". From there you can choose your own password.

Comment: The part I can't figure out is how to keep internet running through the hotspot. Wifi reception is really bad in my room, however if I walk right outside my door, I have all the internet I need. I want to create a hotspot with my kali linux laptop, and stream the internet through here. I think i have to have a hardwired connection, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about The other given answer but what worked for me was the following:

1- nano the following file

nano  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot

2- The information should be like this

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=8848099e-7a0f-46c5-8264-bb6c2a3aa5e1
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
permissions=
secondaries=

[wifi]
hidden=true
mac-address=A0:88:69:95:92:C3
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
seen-bssids=
ssid=PutTheNameOfTheHotspotHere

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=PutHereThePassword

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

3- Save the file and head to the Network manager as you usually do and enable a hotspot.

Done . (If the hotspot doesn't work from the first time try closing the window and enable it again , not sure why but it seems like the first time will only set the card but not enable it .)